# How to get timezone from facebook with omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

Everything in user.rb is passing correctly upon sign up except timezone. I can't figure out why I'm getting this **error** upon a user attempting to sign in:

```
2016-03-30T20:13:38.083469+00:00 app[web.1]:   NoMethodError (undefined method `timezone=' for #<User:0x007fdd2976e338>):
2016-03-30T20:13:38.083470+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:72:in `block in from_omniauth'
2016-03-30T20:13:38.083471+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:66:in `tap'
2016-03-30T20:13:38.083471+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:66:in `from_omniauth'
2016-03-30T20:13:38.083472+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `facebook'
```

**user.rb**

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     # Sets 60 day auth token
     oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("1540371223342976229929", "ee917abf2e8f1c98274cd323fa1234ebb1346f4") # Fake Numbers
     new_access_info = oauth.exchange_access_token_info auth.credentials.token

     new_access_token = new_access_info["access_token"]
     new_access_expires_at = DateTime.now + new_access_info["expires"].to_i.seconds

    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
      user.timezone = auth.info.timezone
      user.email = auth.info.email unless user.email.present?
      user.oauth_token = new_access_token # auth.credentials.token <- your old token. Not needed anymore.
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.password = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
      user.activated = true
      user.save!
    end
  end
```

**config/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, "1540324372976229929", "ee917abf2e8423f1c98274cdfa234234ebb1346f4", {info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name, timezone'}
end
```

`t.float    "timezone"` [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) says timezone should be `float`.

Comment: Are timezones getting saved correctly? From the [auth hash](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#auth-hash) that Facebook provides, it looks like the hash structure is different. -> `auth.extra.raw_info.timezone`

Comment: Timezone isn't getting saved at all. Getting error I mentioned. I'll give that a try and let you know how it goes :] @JustinLicata

Comment: However, that error also looks like you don't have a timezone column on the users table.

Comment: No you were right @JustinLicata. It worked :] You mind providing an answer and maybe how I can turn float timezone, like `timezone: -4.0` into `time_zone_select`? I know that's beyond scope of question so no problem if not. Just trying to figure that part out now :]

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, ask another question and I'll take a look at it. It'll 1) need more information to solve and 2) you could get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the auth hash provided by omniauth has a bit of a different structure than what you are using. Try this.

```
user.timezone = auth.extra.raw_info.timezone
```

[Here is the hash structure](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#auth-hash) that is available for Facebook omniauth.

Comment: I continued the conversation over here if you want to join :] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319711/how-can-i-convert-float-number-to-timezone