# How can I convert float number to timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, timezone, omniauth-facebook

How can I convert `float` number to timezone?

Facebook breaks the timezone down using float.

```
timezone    float (min: -24) (max: 24)
            The person's current timezone offset from UTC
```

`user.timezone = auth.extra.raw_info.timezone` captures a user's timezone location upon signing up via Facebook, for example `timezone: -5.0`.

I want to convert this though to `timezone: "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"`. A user could then adjust his timezone via `<%= f.time_zone_select :timezone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones %>`.

Potential Solution

```
t.float    "timezone"
t.string   "time_zone" # somehow turning it into a string after Facebook sets it?
```

Comment: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(user.timezone).name`?

Comment: well you have to have a user sorry. so for your example above: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(-5.0).name`

Comment: Time zones are pretty fussy at the best of times. -5.0 *could* be that, or it could be [any of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets#UTC.E2.88.9205:00.2C_R), but with Daylight Saving Time in effect, the one you indicated is actually -4.0.

Comment: Ah okay haha thanks for clarifying @tadman. Facebook actually generated `timezone: -4.0`, which I was confused by because I'm in Florida. I figured I'd tackle that problem for another day and just move forward with `-5.0` as my example. Now I won't have that hanging over my head :]

Comment: Time zone != Offset.  Therefore, the task is impossible.  Facebook lies.  It's just the user's offset as of their last login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` class pass in the float as your argument. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html.

*Disclaimer*: Part of the answer comes from the first part of this question, [How to get timezone from facebook with omniauth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319108/how-to-get-timezone-from-facebook-with-omniauth/36319508?noredirect=1#comment60262719_36319508).

```
user.timezone = auth.extra.raw_info.timezone
user.time_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(user.timezone).name
```

You will have to account for times when `user.timezone` is nil, or else it will throw errors.